# Wicket - Relative Image Path without Mounting Page

Tags: image, wicket, mount

I have a little problem with image relative path and not-mounted page in Wicket.

Take this code inside a generic Page (ex MyPage.java):

```
final DatePicker<Date> date = new DatePicker<Date>("date",true);
date.setButtonImage("img/calendar.gif");
```

**img** directory is stored inside **WebContent** directory.

The image is not correctly showed unless I mount the page in WebApplication.
Without mounting the page, the relative url has to be considered starting from the java class path.

How Can I build the correct image url from WebContent without mounting the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the path you can use

```
date.setButtonImage(UrlUtils.rewriteToContextRelative("img/calendar.gif", getRequestCycle()));
```

That's how [ContextImage](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/image/ContextImage.html) works. If your DatePicker would accept another component as the image you could use this class directly.

Answer (score 1):

After searching on google, I found a simple solution.

```
ServletContext servletContext = WebApplication.get().getServletContext();
String contextPath = servletContext.getContextPath();
```

and then

```
date.setButtonImage(contextPath+"/img/calendar.gif");
```